# Character counting program, character as ints issue

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, char, integer

The if statement never triggers so all the values are printed out as 0 in the second for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100] = "this is A TEST";
    int count[26] = {0};
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if((string[i] + '0') == (i + 97) || (string[i] + '0') == (i + 65)){
            count[i]++;     
        } 
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        printf("%c: %d \t", i+97, count[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add `'0'` instead of plain `0` and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Pavan Still not working, trying to print out the alphabet a-z with the amount of occurrences of each in an inputted string

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Stop writing complex, compound boolean expressions.  Use intermediate temp booleans,  You may then have some chance of actually debugging your own code.  Also, learn how to use brackets.

Comment: @Pavan trying to print out the alphabet a-z with the amount of occurrences of each in an inputted string

Comment: @MartinJames What do you mean by intermediate temp booleans?

Comment: `i` is a *string index iterator*, so it runs from `0` to `len(string)-1`. Why would you add the character code for `a` to it? You need to think that over.

Comment: You should consider using const int for 26, like `const int max_size = 26;`

Comment: Use `ctypes.h`. At least don't use _magic numbers_

Comment: People seem to have an odd fascination with the Basic Latin letters, which aren't even sufficient for the English writing system or even identifiers in modern programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use magic numbers like `65` and `97`. Use the characters `'A'` and `'a'` instead. You have to test each `char c` if it is a letter. If the letter is uppercase the number of the character in the alphabet is `c-'A'` and if it is lowercase it is `c-'a'`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ALPHABET_SIZE ('Z'-'A'+1)

int main (void)
{
    char string[100] = "this is A TEST";
    int count[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {0};

    for ( int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++ ) // for all charecters in the string
    {
        char c = string[i];
        if ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' )           // test if c is uppercase letter
            count[c - 'A'] ++;
        else if ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' )      // test if c is lowercase letter
            count[c - 'a'] ++;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++ )
        printf( "%c: %d \t", 'a'+i, count[i] ); 

    return 0;
}
```

Note this code works for ASCII characters, because `'A'`-`'Z'` and `'a'`-`'z'` are represented consecutively.

The following code will works for any character set:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>  // toupper, isupper
#include <limits.h> // UCHAR_MAX 

#define NO_OF_CHAR (UCHAR_MAX+1)

int main (void)
{
    char string[100] = "this is A TEST";
    int count[ NO_OF_CHAR ] = {0};

    for ( int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++ )   // for all charecters in the string      
    {
        unsigned char c = toupper( string[i] );
        count[ c ] ++;                          // increment character counter
    }

    for ( int c = 0; c < NO_OF_CHAR; c++ )
    {
        if ( count[c] > 0 && isupper( c ) )
            printf( "%c: %d \n", c, count[c] ); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're assuming that `'A'`-`'Z'` and `'a'`-`'z'` are represented consecutively.  That's not standard-compliant per **5.2.1 Character
sets** of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):  *The values of the members of the execution character set are implementation-defined.*.  As @Olaf mentions in his comment above, use the functions such as `isalpha()` provided in `ctypes.h`.

Comment: In addition to ASCII, it also works for character sets that more likely to be used than ASCII. (Of course, they are based on ASCII but you really need to know when it matters that you know the exact character set.) Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char string[] = "this is A TEST";
    unsigned int frequency['Z' -'A' + 1] = { 0 };

    for ( const char *p = string; *p; ++p )
    {
        char c = toupper( ( unsigned char )*p );
        if ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ) ++frequency[c-'A'];
    }

    for ( char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c )
    {
        if ( frequency[c-'A'] ) printf( "%c: %u\t", c, frequency[c-'A'] );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

The program output is

```
A: 1    E: 1    H: 1    I: 2    S: 3    T: 3
```

As for your program then for starters this if statement

```
if((string[i] + '0') == (i + 97) || (string[i] + '0') == (i + 65)){
```

does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The following code aims to be fully compliant with the C Standard and work with any character set:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char string[] = "This is a test.";
unsigned int frequency[ UCHAR_MAX + 1 ] = { 0 };

int main( void )
{
    /* this counts ALL characters */
    for ( char *p = string; *p; p++ )
    {
        unsigned char uc = ( unsigned char ) *p;

        /* convert letters to upper case */
        uc = toupper( uc );
        ( frequency[ uc ] )++;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++ )
    {
        /* output only upper-case results */
        if ( isupper( i ) )
        {
            printf( "Char: %c, frequency: %u\n",
                ( char ) i, frequency[ i ] );
        }
    }

    return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for pointing that out.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many mistakes in the code, However the below snippet will do fine

```
for(i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(string[i] >=97 && string[i] < 122){
        count[string[i]-97]++;     
    } 
    if(string[i] >=65 && string[i] < 91){
        count[string[i]-65]++;     
    }
}
```

At first you check whether the string contains a valid character,
And then irrespective of the case you increment it's count in the `count` array

You need to decrease the character by the ascii value of `a` or `A` depending on whether it's lower case or upper case `(97 or 65)` respectively to obtain it's base value.
Base value refers to it's displacement from `a` or `A`

Some inputs : Try using a **hashmap**
Always use string functions like `strlen` which would help you do predefined stuff.